# Python argparse: nargs + or * depending on prior argument

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a server querying tool, and I have a little bit of code to parse arguments at the very top:

```
# Parse arguments
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
g = p.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
g.add_argument('--odam', dest='query_type', action='store_const',
        const='odam', help="Odamex Master query.")
g.add_argument('--odas', dest='query_type', action='store_const',
        const='odas', help="Odamex Server query.")
p.add_argument('address', nargs='*')
args = p.parse_args()

# Default master server arguments.
if args.query_type == 'odam' and not args.address:
    args.address = [
            'master1.odamex.net:15000',
            'master2.odamex.net:15000',
            ]

# If we don't have any addresses by now, we can't go on.
if not args.address:
    print "If you are making a server query, you must pass an address."
    sys.exit(1)
```

Is there a nicer way to do this, preferably all within the parser?  That last error looks a little out of place, and it would be nice if I could make nargs for address depend on if --odam or ---odas is passed.  I could create a subparser, but that would make help look a little odd since it would leave off the addresses part of the command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with an custom [argparse.Action](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action):

```
import argparse
import sys

class AddressAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, args, values, option = None):
        args.address=values
        if args.query_type=='odam' and not args.address:
            args.address=[
                'master1.odamex.net:15000',
                'master2.odamex.net:15000',
                ]        
        if not args.address:
            parser.error("If you are making a server query, you must pass an address.")

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
g = p.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
g.add_argument('--odam', dest='query_type', action='store_const',
        const='odam', help="Odamex Master query.")
g.add_argument('--odas', dest='query_type', action='store_const',
        const='odas', help="Odamex Server query.")
p.add_argument('address', nargs='*', action=AddressAction)
args = p.parse_args()
```

yields

```
% test.py --odas
If you are making a server query, you must pass an address.
% test.py --odam
Namespace(address=['master1.odamex.net:15000', 'master2.odamex.net:15000'], query_type='odam')
% test.py --odam 1 2 3
Namespace(address=['1', '2', '3'], query_type='odam')
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: It probably makes more sense to use [parser error](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.error) instead of `sys.exit()`

Comment: One downside of using a custom action is that the action is called when the argument is parsed, and arguments after the one in question have not yet been added to the values array. This makes optional arguments sensitive to order. To avoid this, dont add a custom action, just check the dependency after the main call to parse_args, and call p.error('explanation message') if the dependecy fails. This prints out the help text and exits.

Comment: I don't understand what is going on in your example. When you run `test.py --odas`, you get "`If you are making a server query, you must pass an address.`", but looking in your code, you do `g.add_argument('--odas', dest='query_type', action='store_const', const='odas', help="Odamex Server query.")`, so for the `odas` option, you don't seem to specify the `AddressAction` action, which is what prints that message. So why is that message printed then? Is this a typo or have I misunderstood the code?